# MDX query metadata pane icons key?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, mdx

In Sql Management studio MDX query designer, there's the metadata pane from which you can drag elements of the cube into your query.

Is there a key for the icons anyway?

There's six dots in a pyramid, another has six dots in two vertical rows of three. Not sure what the folder icon represents under a dimension, etc. That's not the only ones, so I'd really like a key. Any ideas? Couldn't find it in the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the icons become obvious once you've had experience creating a number of dimensions. Many of them are obvious by the label that's next to them. Here's a list of a few of the others:

[image: Measure] Measure
[image: Calculated Measure] Calculated Measure
[image: Dimension] Dimension
[image: Attribute Hierarchy] Attribute Hierarchy
[image: User-Defined Hierarchy] User-Defined Hierarchy
[image: Level 1] Level 1 of User-Defined Hierarchy
[image: Level 2] Level 2 of User-Defined Hierarchy
[image: Member Property] Member Property

The folder icon underneath the dimension that you're talking about is most likely to hold the member properties.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. I don't use the query designer much, I was actually hoping to reconcile what I have been seeing through code with what I saw in the query designer :) Thank you again